# Hide 1 Element From Scrambled Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, element

I have a simple problem to solve, I really have no idea how to. So, I am using this javascript element scrambler. https://jsfiddle.net/C6LPY/2/. And the element scrambler scrambles random divs with seperate numbers. Only the elements inside `<div id="shuffle">` get scrambled. But the point is, I don't want all scrambled elements to show. I only want one scrambled element to show. Every time, I only want one element to get scrambled and others get hidden. Maybe assign style="display: none;" to other elements and only show 1 scrambled element. Obviously that one element always gets scrambled on refresh and others get hidden. My version of the javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var parent = $("#shuffle");
    var divs = parent.children();
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
```

```
<div id="shuffle">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you further detail the desired behavior here? Do you want to shuffle only two elements? You cannot shuffle only one, it has to take the place of another, so two is minimum. Also, where are the 100 elements in your HTML? And what are the `<ins>` tags for?

Comment: I just want to shuffle 2 elements with values 1 and 2. I changed it so its simple. They do get shuffled because the script does work. But, I want one element to be hidden from the 2 shuffled elements. @GhassenLouhaichi

Comment: So in your code, you only have two elements to shuffle, not 100 like the Fiddle. If that's true, which of the two you want to show and which one you want to hide? What's the criteria?

Comment: Well, I want to hide the element with the value 2. And only show the element with value 1 but, I want it to shuffle aswell. So it changes to value 2 on refresh. And then back to 1. Like usual. I just dont want the element with value 2 to be shown maybe hidden.

Comment: Sounds like you always want your 2 div to be hidden if I understood correctly. If so, how about styling it as follows: `<div style="visibility: hidden;">2</div>`? Is that what you expected?

Comment: I figured it out all, I had to do was hide one element behind the content hah, but thanks nevertheless.